# sum a complex dictionary using linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have this structure

```
    class DailyData
    {
        public double A=0.0;
        public double B=0.0;
        public double C=0.0;

    }

SortedDictionary<DateTime,DailyData[]> Data = new SortedDictionary<DateTime,DailyData[]>();
var LongData = Data.Skip(Math.Max(0, Data.Count() - 90)).Take(90);
```

How do I sum (or other ops) a particular value in a section of my dictionary?

i.e I would like to sum all "A"s in LongData?

EDIT

Actually, I don't want all "A"s. I only want to sum all "A"s for element(index) N of my DailyData array. I should have specified that earlier sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Work it out from the types. What do we have? `longData` is of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DailyData[]>`. What do we need?  `IEnumerable<double>`, that we can sum. How are we going to get there?

First thing is to get a sequence of `DailyData[]`:

```
IEnumerable<DailyData[]> q1 = from pair in longData 
                              select pair.Value;
```

OK, now that we have that, let's make a sequence of `DailyData`:

```
IEnumerable<DailyData> q2 = from array in q1 
                            from element in array
                            select element;
```

Now we can obtain the desired sequence of doubles:

```
IEnumerable<double> q3 = from data in q2
                         select data.A;
```

And now we have something we can sum:

```
double sum = q3.Sum();
```

Now that we've broken it down into a series of small steps we can see how to put it together into something more concise:

```
var query = from pair in longData 
            from element in pair.Value
            select element.A;
double sum = query.Sum();
```

Make sense? When using LINQ, some things to remember:

- Use the type system to direct you. The type system indicates the "shape" of the data, so follow it.
- Break down the query into many sub-queries, each of which performs a simple step. Then you can figure out how to write it into something concise later if you want.
- Always remember that the value of a query comprehension expression is *the query* and not *the results*. q1, q2, q3 and query all do no work other than allocating *the query*. None of the queries are actually executed until Sum is called.

Comment: Actually, I don't want all As. I want all As for Index n of my DailyDat array

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options. You can use the [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549046.aspx) method like this:

```
var sum = LongData.SelectMany(x => x.Value).Sum(x => x.A);
```

Or this:

```
var sum = LongData.Sum(x => x.Value.Sum(y => y.A));
```

Or this:

```
var sum =
    (from x in LongData
     from y in x.Value
     select y.A).Sum();
```

Comment: @Kenneth: He's summing the `A` member of each instance.  It will certainly work.

Comment: Because he doesn't have a Dictionary<DateTime, DailyData> but a Dictionary<DateTime, DailyData[]>

Comment: @Kenneth: Oh, geez, didn't even see that.  Use `SelectMany` first or `Sum` the `Sum`s then.

Comment: Or like my answer, sum of a sum: Data.Sum(x => x.Value.Sum(y => y.A));

Comment: @EdS: the reason it doesn't work is that the type of x is DailyData[], not DailyData. See my answer for how I suggest to do it (tested in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in sum operator of LINQ, you just need to select all the values:

```
var sum = Data.Sum(x => x.Value.Sum(y => y.A));
```

Comment: How do I just sum As for Index n of my DailyData array?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to sum all "A"s in LongData

```
LongData.SelectMany( x=>x.Value ).Sum( x=>x.A );
```